# Filter on Dats pandas dataframe (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

somehow I have a problem filtering dates in the dataframe. I used loc on the dataframe but somehow it does not work  and I still receive the full data in my dataframe. The code is:

```
data_dataframe.loc['2015-12-01':'2015-12-31']  
print(data_dataframe)
```

The dataframe looks like the following:

```
         FACT_DATE  Values  
0       2015-12-01      0.91582   
1       2015-12-02      0.882980   
2       2015-12-03      0.848790      
...
```

I also checked the indexing:

```
Index(['FACT_DATE', 'Values'], dtype='object')
```

Why can't I slice the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because need [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html):

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
data_dataframe['FACT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data_dataframe['FACT_DATE'])
#set column to index
data_dataframe = data_dataframe.set_index('FACT_DATE')

#change data for not match all rows
data_dataframe = data_dataframe.loc['2015-12-01':'2015-12-02']  
print(data_dataframe)
             Values
FACT_DATE          
2015-12-01  0.91582
2015-12-02  0.88298
```